# Display all contents of a "table" created in LINQ in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, arrays, linq

Working from a previous question I asked (which was answered very well).. Ive come across another snag... In the following code

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim EntireFile As String
    Dim oRead As System.IO.StreamReader
    oRead = File.OpenText("testschedule.txt")
    EntireFile = oRead.ReadToEnd

    Dim table As New List(Of List(Of String))

    ' Process the file
    For Each line As String In EntireFile.Split(Environment.NewLine)
        Dim row As New List(Of String)
        For Each value In line.Split(",")
            row.Add(value)
        Next

        table.Add(row)
    Next

    ' Display all contents of 5th column in the "table" using LINQ 

    Dim v = From c In table Where c(5) = ""


    For Each x As List(Of String) In v
        Console.WriteLine(x(0)) ' printing the 1st column only
    Next

    Console.WriteLine("Value of (2, 3): " + table(1)(2))
End Sub
```

`

The area where it says `Dim v = From c In table Where c(5) = ""`  the blank quotations will only accept a specific number that its looking for in that column.
For Example:

`Dim v = From c In table Where c(5) = "7"` Will only show me any 7's in that column. Normally there will be many different values and I want it to print everything in that column, I just cant figure out the command to have it display everything in the selected column

Once again **Many MANY** Thanks!

Comment: could you revise your question? its litle confusing after the code. Just see if you can clarify `What exactly you are asking for`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show all rows (to be precise: items in the `IEnumerable`), just remove the `Where` condition

```
Dim v = From c In table
```

Just a note: `table` is not a very good name for your list, it leads the thought to SQL. This is just Linq2Objects and you don't query tables you query plain objects with a syntax very similar to Linq2SQL that in turn is heavily inspired by SQL.

Comment: Ah, see I was under the impression that it worked like SQL and actually created a table... In a sense I want to create a table and in SQL terms "Select everything from Column 5" and print it on the screen... Thats where I got confused.

Comment: The nice thing is that they are just a library of regular (extension) methods operating on collections of regular objects (when using as Linq2Objects). [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) has written a blog post series [Reimplementing LINQ to Objects: Part 45 - Conclusion and List of Posts](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/02/23/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-45-conclusion-and-list-of-posts.aspx) about how it might be implemented behind the scenes.